# Retrofit POST request with a complex JSON

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, pojo

I am new to Retrofit and trying to make a POST request using Retrofit. My POST request has a body which is complex JSON like this:

payload :

```
{
    "user": {
        "personal_info": {
            "first_name": "Walter",
            "last_name": "White",
            "date_of_birth": "1972-01-03 00:00:00 PST"
        },
        "address_info": {
            "address_1": "308 NEGRA ARROYO LANE",
            "address_2": "#",
            "city": "ALBUQUERQUE",
            "state": "NM",
            "zip_code": "87104"
        },
        "contact_info": {
            "email": "wwhite@test.com",
            "telephone": "88888888888",
            "telephone_type_id": 1
        },
        "employment_info": {
            "employer_name": "SELF",
            "employment_status_id": 7,
            "annual_income": 9000000000000000,
            "monthly_income": 750000000000,
            "employment_start_year": 0,
            "employment_start_month": 0
        }
      }
    }
```

I have the interface defined as

```
    @POST("/users")
    void registerUser(@Body User User, Callback<User> cb);
```

I am not sure how my User class should look like, I want the payload to be same as mentioned above, so far I have my User class as

```
public class User {


    @SerializedName("personal_info")
    private PersonalInfo personalInfo;
    @SerializedName("address_info")
    private AddressInfo addressInfo;
    @SerializedName("contact_info")
    private ContactInfo contactInfo;
    @SerializedName("employment_info")
    private EmploymentInfo employmentInfo;

}
```

I am not sure if Personalinfo, ContactInfo etc should be separate classes with all the fields mentioned in JSON request or should I just have them as inner class in the User class and how to make the Retrofit call with User class. Server response is exactly similar to the JSON request mentioned above with 1 additional field i.e User Id. I have the POJO classes ready to get the response.

I am confused on how to make the POST request. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `User` object when serialized will have this JSON representation:

```
{
    "personal_info": {
        "first_name": "Walter",
        "last_name": "White",
        "date_of_birth": "1972-01-03 00:00:00 PST"
    },
    "address_info": {
        "address_1": "308 NEGRA ARROYO LANE",
        "address_2": "#",
        "city": "ALBUQUERQUE",
        "state": "NM",
        "zip_code": "87104"
    },
    "contact_info": {
        "email": "wwhite@test.com",
        "telephone": "88888888888",
        "telephone_type_id": 1
    },
    "employment_info": {
        "employer_name": "SELF",
        "employment_status_id": 7,
        "annual_income": 9000000000000000,
        "monthly_income": 750000000000,
        "employment_start_year": 0,
        "employment_start_month": 0
    }
}
```

In order to build the payload as indicated in the question you need another class:

```
public class UserRequest {

    @SerializedName("user")
    private User user;
}
```

and use it when you perform the request with Retrofit:

```
@POST("/users")
void registerUser(@Body UserRequest User, Callback<User> cb);
```

Comment: Thanks, As I mentioned the server response is exactly the same as the request mentioned above. Is it ok to use the same model classes to parse server response or I should have separate model class for the response.

Comment: Please, can you tell me how will i write User class(my user class is this public class User {

    public String titles  = "Sending report";
    public String Timestamp = "02072015123700";
    public String Type = "Image";
    int  FilesNumber = 1;

}) ,is it right or wrong , and how to to write callback (i am getting back json in call back) , thanks in advance

Comment: @RajanMaurya You should ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

With GSON, there's no difference whether you make those classes top-level or inner, it will work just fine in both scenarios. Your code looks good and should work properly.

Comment: Can I use the same POJO class to handle the response as well?